# Are the 'mail' and 'email' tags synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The differences between these tags are not clear.  When would one use [email](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email), over [mail](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) and vice versa?

Comment: Didn't know I could do that with tag links. Cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the questions using [mail](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) are really referring to emails. I made them synonyms. [mail](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) is remapped to [email](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email).

> updating post history, 51 rows affected
>   updating posts, 37 rows affected
>   updating PostTags associations, 28 rows affected
>   removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
>   updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
>   tag remapping of [email] and [mail] complete!
>   remapping 0 synonyms
>   0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
>   Tag Synonym mail -> email was approved!